# General initializer before Vaadin session

Tags: deployment, initialization, vaadin

I'd like to know how to do general initialization tasks in Vaadin 7.6. Application that take place at deployment time, before incoming HTTP requests. Found some threads that suppose using `AbstractApplicationServlet`. But seems removed in Vaadin 7.

Because I'm quite new to Vaadin I feel a little lost here. What is the way to go? 
Using Jetty 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a task for Vaadin since Vaadin only gets active when the first request is handled by the Vaadin servlet.

You can implement a standard `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`, which is intended for this purpose, and register that in your web.xml. In the listener's `contextInitialized()` method, you can perform your initialization tasks.